# Issue importing model class into a populating script

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am quite new to Django so bear with me, I have read a few Stack Overflow answers on similar but they seem to be much more complicated than what I am trying to do. Any help would be appreciated.

I have followed a tutorial on Udemy which built a website with some models, and then populated them with data using a python script.

From this course; https://www.udemy.com/course/python-and-django-full-stack-web-developer-bootcamp

I am trying to do the same and have followed the steps as analogously as I can. I have;

- declared the models in `app_name/models.py`
- imported them into `app_name/admin.py` and registered them
- included `app_name` in INSTALLED_APPS in `settings.py`

Currently when I log onto the admin of my server I can see the models and add to them. What I cannot seem to do is import the models into my `populate.py` script which is located in the top level folder.

The script is as follows;

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project_name.settings')

import django
django.setup()

import pandas as pd
import glob
from app_name.models import Model_Name
```

I am getting the following error;

```
RuntimeError: Model class app_name.models.Topic doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I am not sure whether I have posted all of the relevant information, so do let me know if I can add anything.

File structure is a follows;

```
project_name
  __pycache__
  __init__.py
  asgi.py
  settings.py
  urls.py
  wsgi.py
app_name
  __init__.py
  admin.py
  apps.py 
  models.py
  tests.py
  views.py
db.sqlite3
manage.py
populate.py
```

The contents of INSTALLED_APPS is the following

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app_name'
]
```

Comment: Your script mentions `smart_plug` but your listed structure talks about `app_name`. Which is it?

Comment: smart_plug is the name of the app, I have changed it to app_name just to make it as generic as possible, I obviously had missed one sorry

Comment: it should all be in terms of app_name now

Comment: You may have better luck making your populate script a custom management command á la https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/# – that way Django is definitely correctly initialized once your `def handle()` gets called.

Comment: I have realised that the code was actually not a problem, but I was running it in an Atom notebook and needed to restart the kernel, it then started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to populate with ORM I mean django shell? In your case I would create custom command instead of populate.py file. It would be pretty easier for you to use.

Comment: I have been able to add to the models in the Django shell. Where would the custom command be defined to populate the models? Do you have any documentation on this, it is only my second day of learning Django

Comment: You can follow this documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management . Pretty easy to use. Just don't forget to use names that its given on documentation like directory name must be management then commands and so on.

Comment: Great thanks, would the population of the db happen within the handle() function?

Comment: I used once as similar case as yours. You can find code in here :https://github.com/nokia-wroclaw/innovativeproject-django-sourcerer/tree/master/django_sourcerer just go to management directory would be enough. Also you are calling the command as file name below command directory that in my case it was ```./ manage.py update_objects``` . Cheers